# How to write all scraped data to csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop, web-scraping

I have a PYTHON code to scrape data from a website and write it into a CSV file. But after running my code, only the last row(joblink) is displayed in my excel while other rows are empty with the headers only.

Please how do I fix? Below is my codeblock.

```
for x in range(1, 210):

    html_text = requests.get(f'https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?from=submit&actualTxtKeywords=Python&searchBy=0&rdoOperator=OR&searchType=personalizedSearch&luceneResultSize=25&postWeek=60&txtKeywords=Python&pDate=I&sequence={x}&startPage=1').text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

    jobs = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')

    with open('jobberman.csv', 'w+', newline = '',  encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        header = ['Company Name', 'Keyskill', 'Joblink']
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '')
        
        writer.writerow(header)
    
    
        for job in jobs:
            company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ','')
            keyskill = job.find('span', class_ = 'srp-skills').text.replace(' ','')
            joblink = job.header.h2.a['href']


            print(f"Company Name: {company_name.strip()}")
            print(f"Required Skills: {keyskill.strip()}")
            print(f"Joblink: {joblink}")


            print('')

            joblist = [company_name, keyskill, joblink]
            writer.writerow(joblist)
```

Comment: `in my excel` you aren't writing any Excel file. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files. A CSV is just a text file with Values Separated by Commas. When you double-click on a CSV file Excel will import it using the user's locale settings for decimal and field separators. In half the world, the comma is the decimal separator so double clicking on a CSV can produce weird results. Have you opened the CSV file with a text editor?

Comment: no I haven't opened with a text editor. How do I write my code to show all the rows instead of just one(joblink) in my ''jobberman.csv"  file?

Comment: What does that file contain in the first place? It's not clear that there's anything to fix yet

Comment: If you want to create an Excel file you can use eg Pandas and `to_excel` to write data to a real Excel file. Or use `openpyxl` to fully customize the Excel file

Comment: If the real requirement is to retrieve data from an HTML table and save it to an Excel file you could use [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to read the data as a dataframe and [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html?highlight=to_excel#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel) to save it as an Excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is, that you overwrite your contents in each iteration, so perform your outer `for-loop` while file is open.

```
...
with open('jobberman.csv', 'w+', newline = '',  encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    header = ['Company Name', 'Keyskill', 'Joblink']
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

    for x in range(1, 120):
        html_text = requests.get(f'https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?from=submit&actualTxtKeywords=Python&searchBy=0&rdoOperator=OR&searchType=personalizedSearch&luceneResultSize=25&postWeek=60&txtKeywords=Python&pDate=I&sequence={x}&startPage=1').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
        jobs = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')

        for job in jobs:
            company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').get_text(strip=True)
            keyskill = job.find('span', class_ = 'srp-skills').get_text(strip=True)
            joblink = job.header.h2.a['href']

            joblist = [company_name, keyskill, joblink]
            writer.writerow(joblist)
```

##### Example

```
import csv
from csv import writer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('jobberman.csv', 'w+', newline = '',  encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    header = ['Company Name', 'Keyskill', 'Joblink']
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

    for x in range(1, 120):
        #### requesting and scraping info      
        joblist = ['Company Name'+str(x), 'Keyskill'+str(x), 'Joblink'+str(x)]
        writer.writerow(joblist)
```

##### Output

```
Company Name,Keyskill,Joblink
Company Name1,Keyskill1,Joblink1
Company Name2,Keyskill2,Joblink2
Company Name3,Keyskill3,Joblink3
Company Name4,Keyskill4,Joblink4
Company Name5,Keyskill5,Joblink5
Company Name6,Keyskill6,Joblink6
Company Name7,Keyskill7,Joblink7
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But this code doesn't return the content of my scraped data, only returns Company Name, keyskill,, Joblink in different indexes. I need the values of this scraped data to be included in the excel and not just joblink only. thank you for the help

Comment: This is just an example how to change your code, cause the website is not working for me / from my country. Simply adapt it and put your scraping part into the loop

Comment: okay I get. I just tried the code above and it still showed only values for 'joblinks' and no content for 'company_name' and 'keyskill' in the excel file 'jobberman.csv'. I hope you understand me and thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Can't access the site. But give this a try:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['Company Name', 'Keyskill', 'Joblink'])
df.to_csv('jobberman.csv', index=False)   
for x in range(1, 210):
    html_text = requests.get(f'https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?from=submit&actualTxtKeywords=Python&searchBy=0&rdoOperator=OR&searchType=personalizedSearch&luceneResultSize=25&postWeek=60&txtKeywords=Python&pDate=I&sequence={x}&startPage=1').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    jobs = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')

    rows = []
    for job in jobs:
        company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ','')
        keyskill = job.find('span', class_ = 'srp-skills').text.replace(' ','')
        joblink = job.header.h2.a['href']

        row = {
            'Company Name':company_name.strip(), 
            'Keyskill': keyskill.strip(), 
            'Joblink': joblink}
        
        rows.append(row)
        
        print(f"Company Name: {company_name.strip()}")
        print(f"Required Skills: {keyskill.strip()}")
        print(f"Joblink: {joblink}")

        print('') 
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df.to_csv('jobberman.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you @chitown for the try unfortunately am still getting same result; only the content of 'joblink' is displaying in the "jobberman.csv" file. I am so frustrated rn. Don't know how to fix this

Comment: give it one more try, I made a small edit. Also what gets printed out on the cosole?

Comment: thanks for the answer. Using ".get_text(strip=True)" worked the magic.